# ionic angular subscribers not being updated

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs, ionic3

How to reflect changes of an observable on another page.

I have two pages, Page1 and Page2 subscribed to the same Observable.

In **Page1**, I subscribed to it on ionViewDidLoad()

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.basket.getBasket().subscribe(res => {
      this.basketDraft = res;
    });
  }
```

in **Page2**, I made a fresh network call which will update the basket.
But when I go back to Page1 the subscribed block isn't called and the view isn't updated. Shouldn't the page update as the data is being observed?

**Basket.ts**

```
constructor(){
    //create an observable
    this.basketObservable = Observable.create(observer => {
      this._basketObserver = observer;
    });
}
    //return the observables
 getBasket() {
    return this.basketObservable;
}
    //publish to all subscribers
update(_basketDraft:any){
 this._basketObserver.next(_basketDraft)
}
```

How do I make sure changes in Page2 will update Page1 as well?

Comment: Doesn't the answer solve your problem?

Comment: that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are creating your Observable is incorrect. Everytime you do a `subscribe()` you override the `observer` so eventually you only end up with one subscription. Use `Subjects` instead.

In your Basket.ts have a code like:

```
private _basketObserver = new Subject()
public basketObservable = this._basketObserver.asObservable();
constructor() {}

//return the observable
getBasket() {
    return this.basketObservable;
}

//publish to all subscribers
update(_basketDraft:any){
  this._basketObserver.next(_basketDraft)
}
```